# tqdm fails when detecting Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar, jupyter, tqdm

I'm using [`tqdm`](https://tqdm.github.io) to display a progress bar for my code. Sometimes I use the code in the terminal and sometimes I use the code in a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org).

Unless I'm mistaken (probably am or I wouldn't be writing this question), `tqdm` is supposed to automatically determine if I'm in the Jupyter Notebook or in the terminal by using this code:

```py
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm

def extend(index):
    # some code here

# X is a pandas DataFrame defined elsewhere

with mp.Pool(N) as pool:
    results = list(
        tqdm(pool.imap(extend, X.index), total=len(X)))
```

The progress bar is shown nicely in the terminal like this:

```
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████| 15035/15035 [35:02<00:00,  7.15it/s]
```

But when the same code is called in a Jupyter Notebook, this is displayed instead:

```
HBox(children=(HTML(value=''), FloatProgress(value=0.0, max=15035.0), HTML(value='')))
```

Am I doing something wrong? **What do I need to do to get `tqdm` to display nicely in Jupyter Notebook *and* in the terminal?**

Comment: Looks like you don't have `jupyterlab_widgets`. Can you provide more information about your environment (python/jupyterlab/conda versions, etc)?

Comment: @AlexMaystrenko yes, it's true that I don't have that. I guess I didn't realize that was needed

Comment: @AlexMaystrenko That's exactly what I needed. Turn your comment into an answer and I'll give you magical internet points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are editing the notebook in the JupyterLab, you should install `jupyterlab_widgets`.